# Bad Shading on Imported Mesh

Tags: modeling, shaders

I have imported a mesh (AutoCad DXF) and I'm experiencing strange shading behavior. I've done the following to try and address the problem with no luck:

Recalculate Normals
Remove Doubles
Delete Loose Geometry
Cleared Seam, Sharp, and Bevel Weights

There are no modifiers on the mesh.

The original imported mesh looks fine in smooth shading but I need the mesh to be in quads which causes the shading to mess up as shown in photo. I can add my .blend file but I'm not sure how to do that.

[image]

Comment: yes please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is generally caused by custom normal data.

Under the *Properties Window > Object Data > Geometry Data* press *Clear Custom Split Normals* to get rid of it.

[image]