# The material look odd with the change of Lamp shadow

Tags: mesh, texturing

The material or the texture look odd, it change with the Lamp.
The first three pictures below show the changes in blender render.

And I also write the script to change texture to cycle, but when i change to cycle render,  some objects look odd, like the picture 4.
I use more picture to show another object.
The order is blender render with Lamp withou shadow, the second one is with Lamp shadow, and the last one is cycle render

[image]
blender render without light shadow

[image]
blender render and the light chose ray shadow

[image]
Cycler

[image]
The order is blender render with Lamp withou shadow, the second one is with Lamp shadow, and the last one is cycle render

Comment: Was the model imported from a different program or format? Clear custom split normals: See: [bad shading on imported mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133816/bad-shading-on-imported-mesh/133819#133819) or [Strange black shading can not light mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles)

Comment: It was imported from the same problem. I have many objects and some objects didn't appear this problem.