# Rendered textures and shape look different than in viewport render preview

Tags: modeling, rendering, color

I'm working on a car model and in viewport render preview, everything looks fine. But when I try actually render the image, the entire color pallet is messed up and the mesh in the grille is the wrong shape. I double checked, but I don't have any imported mesh that could be causing the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project, render engine, materials and modifiers. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings. Also don't crop the images so tight, sometimes there is important infomation in the interface ans settings

Comment: Maybe try Properties panel > Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Bad Shading on Imported Mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133816/bad-shading-on-imported-mesh/133819#133819)

Comment: CTRL+a apply scale?

Comment: After some more Googling I figured out a solution to my issue. By removing the mirror modifiers I had on the car, the colors rendered as a solid colors instead of this weird pattern.