# Dark shadow on some faces, already recalculated normals and merged vertices

Tags: normals

I'm encountered similar problems a few times and can't figure it out. I have simple low poly mesh, normals are correct and there are no extra vertices but still some faces look darker.

[image: Flat Shading]

flat shading mode

Proof of no extra vertices
https://gfycat.com/niftyshockedclingfish.gif

Comment: Merging faces by Distance with the default value only works, if the vertices share almost the exact same coordinate. It looks like you have copied vertices that are of by a tad more than that. Try Merge by Distance again, but change the distance value (bottom left corner) to a higher value

Comment: I did the same thing but there are no extra vertices.

Comment: Looks quite like a duplicate of this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133816/bad-shading-on-imported-mesh or linked one in there

Answer (score 1):

This error is most probably caused by shade smooth.
To fix this go to object data properties -> Normals -> Check the Auto Smooth Checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to shade flat (Object mode, right-click or press <kbd>W</kbd> and there is an option)? And move the vertex. Maybe there is more than one.

Comment: There is no extra vertices I checked few times and the image I posted is already flat shaded. Also I tried smooth shaded too but nothing changed.

Comment: select those dark faces and press on f3 and search for flipped normals try that

Comment: Nothing changed :(